# RecyclerView of Android Studio is not displaying any content

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I create a RecyclerView to display the ImageView and TextView. But whenever i launch the app, the data which are stored in List are not displaying on the activity. What is problem in my code. Please help.

Here is my Adapter Class:

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<DataModel> userList;

public DataAdapter (List<DataModel> userList){
    this.userList = userList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_design, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DataAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    int imageResource = userList.get(position).getImageview();
    String mainName = userList.get(position).getMainTitle();
    String subName = userList.get(position).getSubTitle();
    String dateName = userList.get(position).getDateTitle();

    holder.setData(imageResource,mainName,subName,dateName);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return userList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private ImageView imageView;
    private TextView mainView;
    private TextView subView;
    private TextView dateView;
    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profileImage);
        mainView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mainTitle);
        subView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subTitle);
        dateView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dateTitle);
    }
    public void setData(int image, String str1, String str2, String str3){
        imageView.setImageResource(image);
        mainView.setText(str1);
        subView.setText(str2);
        dateView.setText(str3);
    }
}
```

}

And MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView recyclerView;
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
List<DataModel> userList;
DataAdapter adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initData();
    initRecyclerView();
}

private void initData() {

    userList = new ArrayList<>();
    userList.add(new DataModel(R.drawable.cpp,"C++","Version 10","10:54PM"));
    userList.add(new DataModel(R.drawable.messi1,"Java","Version 9.0","10:54PM"));
    userList.add(new DataModel(R.drawable.python,"Python","Version 15.0","10:54PM"));
}

private void initRecyclerView(){
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    layoutManager.setOrientation(RecyclerView.VERTICAL);
    adapter = new DataAdapter(userList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

}

the item_design.xml which contains imageview and textview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="95dp"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        app:cardCornerRadius="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profileImage"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/cpp" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mainTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="Demo Text"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dateTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="10:17PM"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/mainTitle"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subTitle"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="Version 10"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mainTitle"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the recyclerview of MainActivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please also add where you have recyclerview in your xml.

Comment: CardView must be the root in  item_design.xml

Comment: @Style-7 can you explain more clear about it ?

Comment: You are only missing the line which i answered. I have replicated your code

Answer (score 0):

You have missed this line in your initRecyclerView method

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Please add this, rest of your code is fine.